# VB Application error when open/write a .doc file

Tags: vb.net

Probably, this is an obvious question but I am not very expert about Microsoft world and his language/software.

I have installed an old application rewritten in VB language. This application works on a IIS 8.5 webserver as a site in a Windows 8 server. Moreover, for complete the informations on this server are installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319 and ASP.NET 4.7.3163.0.

In a page there is a piece of code that open/write a .doc file.

However, this doesn't work and this application returns this error instead:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I report here a piece of the code that seems to cause this issue:

```
dim MyWord      as new msword_net.Application
....
MyWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=Server.MapPath("....."))
```

To resolve this issue, I have tryed to install Office but it still doesn't work. For completeness, in the bin folder of the site I have found the dll msword_net.dll (but I don't know if I must use it).

Someone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks at all.

**UPDATE**

Recently, to solve this issue I have try to install interop (for Office 2007) and change the code of the application to refer to this library. But it still doesn't work.

Now, the error is this:

**Type 'Word.Application' is not defined.**

However, I have found a reference to this library only in C:\Windows\assembly folder but nothing in the GAC folder of Microsoft.NET folder after I have install interop library.

Important. I am working on a Windows server 2012 r2 64 bit.

Someone have an idea of how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you saying this works on the web server but doesn't work on your development environment? Do you have a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word on your page?

Comment: Hi @Addy. Recently, I have install the Interop (for Office 2007 because is installed this version) but without luck. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a reference to an old office dll. 
You can try searching online for a copy of that particular dll and place it in the correct path as per the project dll reference to see if that fixes it.
Alternatively you could replace the reference to that office dll with a reference to the dll of your version of office. Note that if the methods in the new dll have changed, you may have to update the app accordingly.